# Filter dates after or equal via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, equals, autofilter

I have problem with my macro. I need to show dates after or equal of defined date. But this macro doesn't output anything.

Dates are set as text so I first I change their Number format to `yyyy/mm/dd`, and then I switch it to real date with Find and Replace of "/". Have no idea why it is not working.

My code:

```
Columns("V:V").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy;@"
Selection.Replace What:="/", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=True

.Range("$A$1", "$AF$" & Last_Row).AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:=">=" & CDate("2014/02/27"), Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: Are you sure the underlying start out as strings?  Are you sure the first three lines of code convert those strings to real dates?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in VBA you must always work using american style dates, remembering that the dates separator is #. That means something like:

```
Criteria:=">=#02/27/2014#"
```

or using a calculated criteria:

```
Criteria:=">=" & Format(myDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
```

(backslah in a format string ensures that the next character is used litterally)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is not the solution. Excel is recounting the date format I thing. I can't find out why is macro filtering blanks. I tried to record macro, and the code was same as I have. Weird